# Hide / Disable My Site, My Profile and Social Tags

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, central-administration

I was following these steps to disable social-related functionality on SharePoint 2010 Publishing site, using Central Admin:

http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/11/hide-disable-my-site-my-profile-and.html

When I tried to click on the 'User profile service application' link, I got an error message. I used ULS Viewer to isolate the error as follows:

UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.get_IsSynchronizationRunning()'.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart._LoadStatusAndSettings()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceStatisticsWebPartBase.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Can someone assist me in getting this page to load so I can disable social functionality?

Comment: What is the farm build number (CA -> Manage servers in farm)?

Comment: Build # is 14.0.6029.1000

Comment: Install at least the June 2011 CU (I'd recommend either Feb 2012 or Dec 2012 CUs).  This is an issue with SP1.

Comment: Trevor, can you post this as an answer - thanks for the info :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install at least the June 2011 CU (I'd recommend either Feb 2012 or Dec 2012 CUs). This is an issue with SP1.

Answer (score 0):

If your User Profile Service Application is not functioning, then you will need to resolve that issue before you will be able to update the permissions for the social features.  The error you displayed does not really give us any info to do that.

If you are not currently using the user profiles, and do not have any required tagging/social data, you could simply remove the UPS and disable that social feature, though your ability to support collaboration without this feature set will take a major hit.

Comment: In what way(s) would collaboration take a hit?